# Писал программу (жизнь - смерть), и что-то застрял

Tags: c#

Программа заключается в том, что есть аквариум в котором живут рыбы и акулы, которые едят рыб, нужно узнать за какое кол-во циклов в аквариуме никого не станет.
В чем проблема- нужна подсказка, или доброе слово, которое направит меня на истинный путь и укажет, что я не так в этой жизни делаю))

Суть программы - Есть 2-а типа рыб, "охотник " и "дичь", мы задаем сколько, кого будет в контейнере, а программа должна подсчитать через сколько циклов аквариум опустеет. Также есть условие- рыбки могут умереть из-за времени или если их съедят, а Акула можетт  умреть- из-за нехватки еды или из-за времени(которое ей суждено прожить(задается в коде)) 
+ рыбки и акула могут удваиваться через определенный момент цикла( через сколько циклов произойдет удвоение, тоже указывается в коде)

```
public class ClownFish : ICreature //рыба клоун наследуется от интерфейса "существо"
{
    public int EatenOnCycle;  // был съеден в цикле 

    int  ICreature.Age
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
} 
//
public class Shark : ICreature // Акула наследуется от интерфейса "существо"

{
    public int DiedOnCycle;  // умер в цикле 

    int ICreature.Age  // подсчет лет
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}

 //
 public class CycleResult
{
    public List<ClownFish> EatenClownFish; 
    public List<Shark> StarvedShark;

    public CycleResult()
    {
        StarvedShark = new List<Shark>();
        EatenClownFish = new List<ClownFish>();
    }

}
 //
 public interface ICreature
{
   int Age // Возраст рыбки 
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
 //
 public class CContainer
{
    private int cycle; // Порядковый номер цикла
    private List<ICreature> content;  // Создаю список "созданий" в нашем аквариуме

    public static CycleResult CycleExecute (CContainer iContainer)   // Выполнение программы

    {
        CycleResult result = new CycleResult();
        int creatureIndex = 0;

        List<Shark> hungryShark = new List<Shark>(); // Создал список голодных Акул
        List<ClownFish> avaiavailableClownFish = new List<ClownFish>(); // Создал список живых рыбок

        int newCycleIndex = iContainer.cycle + 1;


        while ( creatureIndex<iContainer.content.Count) // Проверка на наличие рыбок в аквариуме
        {
            ICreature nextCreature = iContainer.content[creatureIndex]; // Искать рыбок я собираюсь по индексу способом перебора
            nextCreature.Age++;

            // Shark or ClownFish
            if (nextCreature is Shark)
            {

                Shark _shark = nextCreature as Shark;

                //Есть ли что покушать?
                if (avaiavailableClownFish.Count > 0)
                {
                    List<ClownFish> food = avaiavailableClownFish;  // живые рыбки - едля для акул
                    avaiavailableClownFish.RemoveAt(0); // едаа
                    // тут явно должно что-то быть но я не знаю что
                }
                else // если нечего есть добавлю голодных акулят
                {
                    hungryShark.Add();    // нуэно что-то добавить, вылазит ошибка
                }
            }
            else if (nextCreature is ClownFish)  // если попалась нам не акула - значит это рыбка
            {
                ClownFish fish = nextCreature as ClownFish;

                //Есть ли кому скормить?
                if (hungryShark.Count > 0)
                {
                    List<Shark> eater = hungryShark;
                    hungryShark.RemoveAt(0);

                    fish.EatenOnCycle = newCycleIndex;
                }
                else
                {
                    avaiavailableClownFish.Add(new List<ClownFish>); // тоже ошибочка 
                }

                creatureIndex++;
            }

            }

        }





        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Опишите правила смерти акул, правила появления новых рыб-жертв и акул (если такое возможно), а также сколько рыб-жертв за цикл съедает каждая акула. По-моему, вы очень переусложнили решение задачи. По поводу _"нужно что-то добавить, вылазит ошибка"_: в список нужно добавлять... элементы. Если у вас список `Shark`, то и добавлять нужно `Shark`. Аналогично со списком `ClownFish` - в него нужно добавлять объекты `ClownFish`, а не какой-то другой список.

Comment: Передавать в статический метод класса `CContainer` объект типа `CContainer` - звучит как очень сомнительное решение. Имеет смысл просто сделать метод нестатическим. `creatureIndex` вместе с `while` и неизменением поля `cycle` явно не помогут в подсчете количества циклов.

Comment: Если в ответе нужно просто число (количество циклов), а на вход подаётся количество рыб-жертв и количество акул, то достаточно работать в рамках чисел, вообще не создавая дополнительные классы.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал для вас начальный шаблон нужного вам функционала

[image: Пример работы программы]

Базовый класс рыбы такой

```
public abstract class Fish
{
    //ctor
    public Fish(string name = "Fish", int vitalPower = 1)
    {
        Name = name;
        VitalPower = vitalPower;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Жизненная сила
    /// </summary>
    public int VitalPower { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Функция жизненного цикла
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="neighborFish">ссылка на соседнюю рыбу</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public abstract bool DoLive(Fish neighborFish);

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name}-{VitalPower}:{Age}";
    }
}
```

Класс Акулы

```
public class Shark : Fish
{
    //ctor
    public Shark(string name, int vitalPower) : base(name, vitalPower)
    {
    }

    public override bool DoLive(Fish neighborFish)
    {
        //если есть еще жизненные силы, проживаем цикл
        if (VitalPower > 0)
        {
            //увеличиваем возраст
            Age++;

            //если соседка существует и ее можно съесть
            if (neighborFish != null && neighborFish is ClownFish)
            {
                //съедаем жертву
                neighborFish.VitalPower = 0;
                neighborFish.Name = "Dead";
                neighborFish.Age++;

                return true;
            }

            //если поживиться было нечем, то уменьшаем силы
            if (--VitalPower == 0)
            {
                //жизненных сил больше нет, рыба умерла
                Name = "Dead";
                return false;
            }

            //рыба все еще жива
            return true;
        }

        //жизненных сил нет, рыба мертва
        return false;
    }
}
```

Класс Аквариума

```
public class Aquarium
{
    //ctor
    public Aquarium(int fishQuantity)
    {
        if (fishQuantity <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(fishQuantity));

        FishQuantity = fishQuantity;
        FishList = new List<Fish>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Общее кол-во рыб
    /// </summary>
    public int FishQuantity { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Кол-во живых рыб
    /// </summary>
    public int LivingQuantity { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Прожито циклов
    /// </summary>
    public int PastCycles { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Cписок рыбок в аквариуме
    /// </summary>
    public List<Fish> FishList { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Заселение аквариума
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="predatorAmount">требуемое кол-во акул</param>
    public void Colonize(int predatorAmount, int vitalPower)
    {
        if (predatorAmount <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(predatorAmount));
        if (vitalPower <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(vitalPower));

        //количество живых рыб
        LivingQuantity = FishQuantity;
        //массив случайных чисел, для расположения акул в списке
        int[] predatorsPositions = GetPositions(predatorAmount);

        FishList = GetListFish(predatorsPositions, vitalPower);
    }

    private List<Fish> GetListFish(int[] predatorsPositions, int vitalPower)
    {
        List<Fish> result = new List<Fish>();
        Fish fish = null;
        int numberShark = 1;
        int numberClownFish = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < FishQuantity; i++)
        {
            if (predatorsPositions.Where(p => p == i).Count() > 0)
            {
                fish = new Shark($"Shark_{numberShark}", vitalPower);
                numberShark++;
            }
            else
            {
                fish = new ClownFish($"ClownFish_{numberClownFish}", vitalPower);
                numberClownFish++;
            }

            result.Add(fish);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private int[] GetPositions(int predatorAmount)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        var array = Enumerable
                        .Range(0, FishQuantity)
                        .OrderBy(i => rnd.Next(0, FishQuantity - 1))
                        .Take(predatorAmount)
                        .ToArray();
        return array;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Проход одного жизненного цикла в аквариуме
    /// </summary>
    public bool DoCycle()
    {
        if (FishList.Count == 0) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(FishList));

        //счетчик жизненных циклов
        PastCycles++;

        //запускаем проживание для каждой рыбы из списка
        foreach (Fish fish in FishList)
        {
            if (fish is Shark)
            {
                Fish prey = FishList.FirstOrDefault(f => f is ClownFish && f.VitalPower > 0);
                fish.DoLive(prey);
                continue;
            }

            fish.DoLive(null);
        }

        //вычисляем количество живых рыб
        LivingQuantity = FishList.Where(f => f.VitalPower > 0).Count();

        return LivingQuantity > 0;
    }

}
```

Ну и запускаем и выводим примерно так

```
//проходим жизненные циклы пока есть живые рыбы
while (aquarium.DoCycle())
{
    Console.Clear();
    PrintAquarium.Output(aquarium);
    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).Wait();
}

//результат
Console.Clear();
PrintAquarium.Result(aquarium);
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine(new String('=', 70));
Console.WriteLine($"Готово!");
```

Весь проект целиком можно скачать [здесь.](https://yadi.sk/d/89Toy33M3L8zua)
Дальше можно и нужно дорабатывать под ваши условия, желаю удачи.

Answer (score 0):

Надо подумать над интерфейсом использования вашего класса. Я не понял, как задать начальное состояние аквариума.

```
var c = new CContainer();
//здесь хотелось бы добавить рыбок
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   var r = CContainer.CycleExecute(c);
   Console.WriteLine("EatenClownFish: {0}, StarvedShark: {1}", r.EatenClownFish.Count, r.StarvedShark.Count);
   //как узнать жизнь в аквариуме завершена и выйти из цикла?
}
```

Добавьте публичный метод инициализации аквариума.

Вот исправленный код CContainer (исправил только ошибки)

```
//
public class CContainer
{
    private int cycle; // Порядковый номер цикла
    private List<ICreature> content = new List<ICreature>();  // Создаю список "созданий" в нашем аквариуме

    public static CycleResult CycleExecute(CContainer iContainer)   // Выполнение программы
    {
        CycleResult result = new CycleResult();
        int creatureIndex = 0;

        List<Shark> hungryShark = new List<Shark>(); // Создал список голодных Акул
        List<ClownFish> avaiavailableClownFish = new List<ClownFish>(); // Создал список живых рыбок

        int newCycleIndex = iContainer.cycle + 1;


        while (creatureIndex < iContainer.content.Count) // Проверка на наличие рыбок в аквариуме
        {
            ICreature nextCreature = iContainer.content[creatureIndex]; // Искать рыбок я собираюсь по индексу способом перебора
            nextCreature.Age++;

            // Shark or ClownFish
            if (nextCreature is Shark)
            {

                Shark _shark = nextCreature as Shark;

                //Есть ли что покушать?
                if (avaiavailableClownFish.Count > 0)
                {
                    List<ClownFish> food = avaiavailableClownFish;  // живые рыбки - едля для акул
                    avaiavailableClownFish.RemoveAt(0); // едаа
                    // тут явно должно что-то быть но я не знаю что
                }
                else // если нечего есть добавлю голодных акулят
                {
                    hungryShark.Add(new Shark());    // нуэно что-то добавить, вылазит ошибка
                }
            }
            else if (nextCreature is ClownFish)  // если попалась нам не акула - значит это рыбка
            {
                ClownFish fish = nextCreature as ClownFish;

                //Есть ли кому скормить?
                if (hungryShark.Count > 0)
                {
                    List<Shark> eater = hungryShark;
                    hungryShark.RemoveAt(0);

                    fish.EatenOnCycle = newCycleIndex;
                }
                else
                {
                    avaiavailableClownFish.Add(new ClownFish()); // тоже ошибочка 
                }

                creatureIndex++;
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `private List<ICreature> content =new List<ICreature>(); `

Comment: исправил, теперь ошибок нет, но и рыбок тоже

Comment: Я по-прежнему за вариант полного переписывания кода автора. Конечно, только в случае, если автор таки сформулирует задачу. Это всё к чему: сдаётся мне, представленный в ответе код решением задачи не является.

Comment: @Regent почему код должен быть переписан полностью? Все так плохо?

Comment: @Regent Я хоть и понимал, что мой код далек от идеала, но чтоб писать его заново, я не расчитывал Что именно не понятно в задаче? Есть 2-а типа рыб, охотник и дичь, мы задаем сколько, кого будет в контейнере, а программа должна подсчитать через сколько аквариум опустеет. Рыбки - умрут из-за времени или их съедят, а Акула - умрет из-за нехватки еды или из-за времени

Comment: @FlyFox это всё стоило написать в комментариях под вопросом, где я об этом спрашивал, а не под данным ответом. Насчет задачи я уже писал: условие смерти акулы, кол-во съеденных акулой рыб-жертв за цикл, возможность появления новых акул и рыб-жертв. Вот насчет того, что рыбы-жертвы и акулы могут умереть просто от времени, вы вообще до этого ничего не писали. Главная проблема вашего кода - переусложнение, если нужно из двух чисел получить третье. В общем, если приведёте **полное** условие задачи в **тексте вопроса** (под ним есть кнопка "Править"), то можно будет подумать над простым решением.

Comment: @Regent да, спасибо, я сделал правку

Comment: @Regent Простите, что опять с тем же вопросом. Как именно можно облегчить программу. Просто это я писал представляя как должен выглядеть цикл ( расписав на бумажке, что должно происходить) и просто искал в учебнике Шилдта, то что я могу использовать в программе. Было много решении программы, н не одно не удавалось закончить( получалась полная хрень

Comment: не надо ничего переписывать. программа написана адекватно той задаче, которая поставлена. когда будете писать сложное веб-приложение или толстый клиент - там и подумаете над правильной архитектурой. забейте на эту задачу и смотрите в направлении новых идей.

Comment: @FlyFox я так и не сподвигся написать решение задачи (на базе вашего или с нуля). Учитывая что все рыбы, оказывается, могут размножаться, а также умирать естественной смертью, то всё становится сложнее и использование доп. классов может быть оправданно. В вашем коде, кстати, я не заметил задания параметров времени естественной смерти и размножения.

Comment: @Regent , вообще, я просто хотел расписать вопрос, в упрощенной форме, и показать, как я реализую программу, чтобы понять и разобраться в теме) Поэтому и вопрос получился не очень сформулирован

Comment: @Regent Здравствуйте, я переписал программу, но она работает не совсем корректно и не очень красиво написана. Сможете, пожалуйста, посмотреть и сказать, что исправить?)

Comment: @FlyFox задайте это отдельным вопросом, хорошо его сформулировав. Во-первых, так больше шансов что вам оперативно помогут (чтобы не ждать когда именно у меня появится на это время). Во-вторых, потому что это не форум, а сайт в ключе "вопрос - ответ",